# Autoincremento do Postgresql pula 1 valor quando o insert é feito por uma função

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte função no `Postgresql`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ve.geraHistorico()
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
DECLARE
    i INTEGER := 1;
    id INTEGER;
    dataCad TEXT;
    dataFec TEXT;
    qtd INTEGER := (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ve.vendas);
BEGIN
    WHILE i <= qtd LOOP
        SELECT id, datacadastro, datafechamento INTO id, dataCad, DataFec FROM ve.vendas WHERE id = i;

        IF dataFec IS NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO ve.historico(id, data)
            VALUES(id, GENERATE_SERIES(dataCad::DATE, CURRENT_DATE::DATE, '1 day'::interval));
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO ve.historico(id, data)
            VALUES(id, GENERATE_SERIES(dataCad::DATE, dataFec::DATE, '1 day'::interval));
        END IF;
        i = i + 1;
    END LOOP;
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

A tabela `ve.historico` é constituída:

```
CREATE TABLE ve.vendas
(
    idAI SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id INTEGER,
    data DATE
);
```

O problema acontece quando eu executo a função `ve.geraHistorico()`, o autoincremento deveria criar um id unico e sequencial para cada linha inserida, porém quando troca o id da venda na função, o autoincremento pula 1 valor, ficando do seguinte jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira coluna (cinza) é o contador do do console do pgAdmin, a segunda coluna é o AUTOINCREMENTO, a terceira é o id da venda e a quarta coluna é as datas que eu estou gerando. Se reparar, vai ver que na linha 31 o AUTOINCREMENTO deveria ser o 31 também, mais pulou por 32, bem onde troca de venda.

Porque isso acontece? Seria algum problema na função?

Comment: não foi outra tentativa de insert que deu errado não ? quando acontece um rollback na transação, a sequence não volta o número que foi gerado na transação

Comment: Eu testei varias vezes, dropei a tabela e executei a função, justamente para zerar o autoincremento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é completamente normal.

Quando você cria um campo em uma tabela do tipo `SERIAL` ou `BIGSERIAL`, uma `SEQUENCE` é criada implicitamente para fazer o controle de auto-incremento desse campo.

Campos do tipo `SERIAL` e `BIGSERIAL` possuem um valor `DEFAULT` que consiste no retorno da chamada da função `nextval()`.

Em um cenário real, várias transações isoladas podem estar chamando `nextval()` para uma mesma `SEQUENCE`, de forma simultanea, umas serão efetivadas e outras serão descartadas.

MESMO as transações descartadas (que sofreram `ROLLBACK`), não decrementam a `SEQUENCE`, fazendo com que aquele numero sequêncial seja perdido para sempre.

Os `gaps` que você está observando, são na verdade, transações que chamaram `nextval()`, porém, sofreram `ROLLBACK` em algum ponto.

A `SEQUENCE` **nunca é decrementada**, nem mesmo se houve um `ROLLBACK` na transação que a incrementou (e fazer esse decremento manualmente não é uma boa idéia!).

Segundo a documentação do `PostgreSQL`, na seção sobre `Manipulação de Sequências`, [há uma explicação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) sobre esse comportamento na referência da função `nextval()`, veja só:

> **nextval**
>
> Advance the sequence object to its next value and return that value.
>   This is done atomically: even if multiple sessions execute
>   `nextval` concurrently, each will safely receive a distinct sequence
>   value.
>
> [...]
>
> *Important*
>
> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the
>   same sequence, a `nextval` operation is never rolled back; that is,
>   once a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be
>   returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later
>   aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value. For
>   example an `INSERT` with an `ON CONFLICT` clause will compute the
>   to-be-inserted tuple, including doing any required `nextval` calls,
>   before detecting any conflict that would cause it to follow the `ON`
>   `CONFLICT` rule instead. Such cases will leave unused “holes” in the
>   sequence of assigned values. Thus, PostgreSQL sequence objects ***cannot
>   be used to obtain “gapless” sequences***.

Já pensou em reavaliar sobre a real necessidade de se ter um campo com sequência sem *gaps* ?

Considere o seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_historico
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  valor INTEGER,
  datahora TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);


BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); ROLLBACK;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); ROLLBACK;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); COMMIT;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); ROLLBACK;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); COMMIT;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); ROLLBACK;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); COMMIT;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); ROLLBACK;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); COMMIT;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); ROLLBACK;
BEGIN; INSERT INTO tb_historico ( valor ) VALUES ( 100 ); COMMIT;
```

Você pode usar a função `row_number()` para enumerar seus registros, veja só:

```
SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS id_gapless,
    id,
    valor,
    datahora
FROM
    tb_historico;
```

Saída:

```
| id_gapless | id | valor |                    datahora |
|------------|----|-------|-----------------------------|
|          1 |  3 |   100 | 2018-07-04T19:07:11.651281Z |
|          2 |  5 |   100 | 2018-07-04T19:07:11.654413Z |
|          3 |  7 |   100 | 2018-07-04T19:07:11.657451Z |
|          4 |  9 |   100 | 2018-07-04T19:07:11.660584Z |
|          5 | 11 |   100 |  2018-07-04T19:07:11.66475Z |
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3edfd/5)

Comment: Deveras interessante. Teria alguma sugestão de como eu poderia contornar essa situação dos gaps?

Comment: @J.Thatcher: Posso te perguntar qual é o motivo para se ter esse campo com sequencias "gapless" ?! Isso é mesmo necessário ? Qual é o intento ?

Comment: Estou precisando gerar o historico da vida de uma venda para ser usado em um B.I.

Comment: @J.Thatcher: Ver edição!

Comment: Muito bom! +1!.

Comment: Não fiz exatamente assim, mas clareou minha mente. Inseri os valores que eu queria em uma temporaria e dei um insert select na temporaria com o row_number, ai uso o row_number como ID. Obrigado pela explicação do nextval().